# Application name appearing below the toolbar

Tags: android, xml

My application name Zenica is not appearing in my toolbar it is appearing below the toolbar. For reference i am attaching an image of it. Moreover i want to keep color of my toolbar different from the rest of the window but when setting the background in the toolbar.xml the color of the complete window gets changed instead of changing only the toolbar color.

[image]

**HomeActivity.java**

```
package com.zenica.app.zenica;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.transition.Slide;
import android.transition.Transition;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;

/**
 * Created by Neha on 03-02-2016.
 */
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar mtoolar;
DrawerLayout dLayout;
private NavigationView navView;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

@TargetApi(21)
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    int currentapiVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (currentapiVersion == Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Transition ts = new Slide();
        ts.setDuration(3000);
        getWindow().setEnterTransition(ts);
        getWindow().setExitTransition(ts);
        setContentView(R.layout.navigation_drawer);
    } else {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.navigation_drawer);
    }
    setToolbar();
    setNavigationDrawer();
}

private void setToolbar()
{
    mtoolar=(Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    dLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    setSupportActionBar(mtoolar);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setElevation(5);
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, dLayout,mtoolar,  R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close)
    {
        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
        }
        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }
    };
   // Set the drawer toggle as the DrawerListener
    dLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

private void setNavigationDrawer() {
    dLayout=(DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    navView=(NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
           int itemId = menuItem.getItemId();

            if (itemId == R.id.home_item) {
                         }
            else if (itemId == R.id.about_app) {
                             }
            return false;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
}
```

**toolbar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
android:elevation="8dp">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.zenica.app.zenica" >
   <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow">

    <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".HomeActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    </activity>

</application>
</manifest>
```

**colors.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryLight">#C5CAE9</color>
<color name="textColorPrimary">#212121</color>
<color name="textColorSecondary">#727272</color>
<color name="windowBackground">#FFFFFF</color>
<color name="navigationBarColor">#000000</color>
<color name="colorAccent">#FF5252</color>
<color name="icons">#FFFFFF</color>
<color name="listDivider">#68FF66</color>
</resources>
```

navigation_drawer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
tools:context=".HomeActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
android:id="@+id/navigation"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="start"
app:itemTextColor="#333"
app:itemIconTint="#ddd"
app:menu="@menu/navigation_items"
    app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"/>

<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar" />

</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: show your layout file navigation_drawer in question

Comment: @DhawalSodhaParmar - See now i have added navigation_drawer.xml file

Comment: https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare compare your code